# Are there a toilet and (small) kitchen in the Su-34?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit, sukhoi-su-34

It seems that there are a toilet and small kitchen in the Su-34. The [Su-34 is a medium range fighter-bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-34) with a range of action of 4000km able to transport 8 tons of bombs and missile.

I know that the pilots enter from the bottom and they sit side by side (so there is some space). Some people say that there is a toilet, some other comforts (microwave,bed) and others say that there is just this:

[image: toilet???]

Is that a toilet? Can you confirm if the Su-34 really has those features?

Comment: I dunno, there seems to be a urinal in my hang glider.  At least, I managed to take care of the issue in some way and my clothes didn't get wet; not sure I can say the same for the people down below on the ground.

Comment: This question needs heavy editing, because the pictures are wrong. However, the Su-34 does indeed include some minimal amenities. I'd vote close if there was a duplicate, but curiously one is missing.

Comment: @Ralph, I can understand your point, but I disagree that the question includes deliberate dis-information.  I think the photo was included as an example, and a minor edit would make it acceptable.  (otherwise, why ask the question if you truly believe you have photographic proof?)  And dispelling dis/mis information is on-topic...

Comment: I've edited out the irrelevant photo. The other photo is from the Su-34.

Comment: The photos are just that i have find.....because i did not know the right and wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Su-34 does technically include a food ration warmer, a "sanitary container", and some room that allows for sleeping.

However, all three are much less impressive than the terms might suggest:

- The food ration warmer is not a microwave. It's just a small can heater:

[image: Ration warmer]

There is also some dedicated room for extra cans.

- The "sleeping room" is just a bit of room where one could fit a sleeping sack. 
  [image: Entry hatch]

One can lay down their head and torso on the entry hatch and fit their legs between the seats. This may come in handy for really long missions, likely with in-air refueling. This is more of a side effect of having an entry ladder and a hatch than a deliberate amenity.

- The "toilet", or "sanitary can" as it's called, is exactly as illustrated in your question. Its interface technically supports both methods, but there's no record or hint of anyone ever using any but the first.

The reason for these is that the Su-34 is meant to be a long-range bomber with enough air-to-air capability to fly unescorted. So, even though based on a modified fighter platform, it was fitted with minimal amenities. However, these amenities are more of a "tick the box" type.

P.S. To correct some premises, ~8,000 kg is the payload limit for most of the Su-27 family, but not the -34. The Su-34 is significantly above that, with a maximum payload of 10,400 kg with maximum fuel or 12,500 kg with reduced fuel. In practical usage, it's an attack aircraft/bomber that can defend itself and operate against extensive air defenses.

To have an idea of where such a concept comes from, look at the [Tu-22M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-22M). While a strategic bomber by role, it's rated up to Mach 2 and 2.5 g, has basic defensive armament, and is meant to engage aircraft carriers. So the VVS idea of a bomber from the 1970s on has been less of a bomb truck and more of an enlarged fighter with a large payload of guided munitions.

The Su-34 is a further development towards a fighter-like bomber direction. It's a heavy fighter platform with added wing area, range and payload to match older bombers. To narrow down its role, consider the F/A-18 for a comparison as an exemplary fighter-bomber that you'd see deployed on A2A missions as easily as A2G. The Su-34, OTOH, is more of a fighter-based bomber that doesn't need a fighter escort, but complements the base models for A2G and leaves A2A missions to Su-30/Su-35 variants.

P.P.S. I've taken the liberty of editing out your 2nd image, as it's from a space station.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. The SU-34 is a tactical jet with ejection seats. There is no room for such amenities.  Most fighter type aircraft only have a relief tube of the type in your upper photo.

Comment: So there us just the object of the first picture. it's a simple cylinder filled with chemicals for odors.however there is a bed behind the pilots normally

Comment: Well that’s not entirely true.  The B1 bomber was equipped with a small commode just behind the commander’s seat, despite being equipped with ejection seats at all four crewmember stations.  It’s not unreasonable to think that an Su-34 would or could be similarly equipped.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is a bed in the SU-34.  If you have proof of this then please post it.

Comment: @CarloFelicione It is indeed true. There is no room for such amenities in the SU-34.

Comment: The B1 is a lot bigger than the SU34, and obviously must have been designed with this in mind.  I don't know the history of the development of the Su34, but just looking at it I would wager it was adapted from a single seat fighter design.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is neither a toilet nor a kitchen on an SU-34. The first picture in your post is of the "relief tube", which the crew can urinate into. It's not a toilet, though, and can't handle feces.

There is a small area behind the crew seats just big enough for one person to stretch their legs, which can be used to store food if the crew so desires. It even has a dedicated bracket for a single thermos. Though I would hardly call that a "kitchen", since it doesn't have a refrigerator, oven, water, cutlery, or anything else that kitchens usually have. It also doesn't have a bed.

The second picture in your post is actually from the MIR space station, and has absolutely nothing to do with the SU-34. I don't know where you even got it from.

Comment: A picture would add a lot to your answer, if you can find one.